# Trace back with Sprite collision -AttributeError: 'Sprite' object has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I am new to using pygame , so please excuse the newbie mistakes I am probably making :)

I am making a game where the user operates one car , and has to dodge the police cars that are running up and down the surface randomly .
I am trying to use `col=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(carImg,hit_list,False)` , with `hit_list` being a `sprite.Group` of the police cars , and carImg being the user operated car . Heres a snipet of the code ;
   `

```
    surface.blit(bg,(0,0))
    hit_list=pygame.sprite.Group()
    #player=pygame.sprite.Group()
    #player.add(carImg)
    hit_list.add(pCar)
    hit_list.add(pCarT)
    hit_list.add(pCarTH)
    hit_list.add(pCarF)

    hit_list.update()
    player.update()

    col=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(carImg,hit_list,False)
    if col==True:
        lost(h,j)`
```

as you can see I have tried carImg (the user operated car) in a sprite.Group (player) as well , but this calls a traceback too.

this is the Trace back I get from running the code

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ali\Documents\snakey things\4carGame - Copy.py", line 133, in <module>
    col=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(carImg,hit_list,False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1345, in spritecollide
    if spritecollide(s.rect):
AttributeError: 'Sprite' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

What am I doing wrong so that the collide does not work?
How would I fix this ?

Many thanks 
Zat

Answer (score 1):

`carImg` does not have a `rect` attribute.

From the [documentation](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite):

> To find the collisions, the Sprites are required to have a Surface.rect attribute assigned.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..how would I assign a Surface.rect ? I am not sure how to implement that . Thanks Zat

Comment: The documentation I linked contains an example with comments which should help you.

Comment: Hi I took a look at the documentation , but I am still not really understanding. Could someone please explain where I would use this is my code ?

Comment: In the `__init__` function of your sprite class.

Answer (score -1):

you have to create a rectangle for every image/sprite you have declared right after the imageload, like:

```
self.carImg = transform.scale(image.load('carImg.jpg').convert(),(100,200))
carImg.rect = self.carImg.get_rect()

self.pcarImg = transform.scale(image.load('pcarImg.jpg').convert(),(100,200))
pcarImg.rect = self.carImg.get_rect()
```